# Does the association bonus count for Running Ragged hat?

Tags: support, winter-bash, winter-bash-2016

From [winterbash2016.stackexchange.com](http://winterbash2016.stackexchange.com/amped-up)

> **Running Ragged**
>
> earn 150 reputation points on three different sites (not including
>   Stack Overflow) within 15 days.

So my query is: association bonus going to be counted for it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The association bonus does not count...now.  You could say there was a bit of an oversight initially and it was counted.  But since you asked this question, we are now excluding the association bonus, so thanks for asking this because we wouldn't want to give out too many hats.

Comment: The Wise Miser  :p

Answer (score 2):

I'm quite sure association bonus doesn't count.

Otherwise you could just sign-up to 3 new sites, get the association bonus in each of them, and you'll only need 50 more rep on each of those sites to get the hat. That would make the hat 3 times less difficult to obtain.

Comment: No loss in confirming

Comment: So it seemed you were wrong @Eran, but not any more. :)

Comment: @PatrickHofman It's good to be right :). I figured the correct answer even before it was correct.